WebRTC audio output not working after handling CallKit in foreground app state
I'm facing an issue where, when the app is in the foreground and I handle an incoming CallKit call CXAnswerCallAction, the app switches to a custom ViewController that opens a WebView embedding WebRTC.
Despite granting microphone permissions, the microphone does not output sound. However, if the app is not open or in the background, opening the same WebView works fine, and the audio is output as expected. Additionally, when opening the same WebView directly without going through CallKit (even when the app is in the foreground), the microphone outputs sound correctly.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or does anyone know why this behavior might be occurring?
I have tried configuring the audio session when answering an incoming call, but I always get the following error:
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=561017449 "Session activation failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Session activation failed}. 
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
    action.fulfill()
    
    let vc = CLPhoneCallViewController()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        vc.showCallScreen()
    }
    
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .voiceChat, options: [.allowBluetooth, .defaultToSpeaker])
        try session.setActive(true)
        
        print("Audio session activated successfully")
    } catch {
        print("Failed to activate audio session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }    
}


